# How to call a webservice from dataflow in SSIS?

Tags: web-services, ssis, batch-file

I need to call a webservice to validate some data.  There is web service task in the control flow but I need to validate during the data flow.  Also, the web service supports single or batch validations so it would be nice to batch a 100 items for validation at a time.

Is it best to just code all this up in a script component?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would code in a script component. The web service stuff is kind of beyond the scope of the traditional purposes of the given SSIS components I think and if you're using SSIS 2008 I'd just write it up in C# and continue on.

Just my opnion.